# Fastest way to replace a checklist subtask by a separate linked task card in Trello

Tags: trello

I often plan team's tasks using Checklist for big task/breakdown-able user story. And each item in that check list, I want it to be a separate task card so that I can put details to such subtask.

Currently what I have to do is

1. Create the checklist
2. Add items
3. Convert items into cards - it gets removed from the checklist
4. Find the created item and get the shared URL
5. Add back the item using the URL
6. Done

Well, repeating such tiring 6-steps above get me mad ^^ Indeed. My 1) [search on oficial trello site](http://help.trello.com/search?query=Trello%20fastest%20way%20to%20replace%20a%20checklist%20subtask%20by%20a%20separate%20linked%20task%20card), 2) on [our stackexchagne webapps site here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=Trello%20fastest%20way%20to%20replace%20a%20checklist%20subtask%20by%20a%20separate%20linked%20task%20card) and 3) [my google search here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=trello%20fastest%20way%20to%20replace%20a%20checklist%20subtask%20by%20a%20linked%20task%20card) - though, I can't find one useful answer for my need.

So my question is, what is the fastest way to convert one checklist item into separate card that still attained in the list?

p.s.

Details as snapshots

Convert checklist item (and GET REMOVED from the checklist!?)
[image]

Get its URL
[image]

Add it back
[image]

Comment: Question: Why are you creating Checklists and then converting items to Cards?  Why not simply create cards in a list in the first place? Use the "Add a card.." link at the bottom of each list.  This method has the advantage of letting you move cards around (up / down the list) as you create new cards.  Once you create the card, open them for the links.

Comment: I guess you don't break down big task into smaller tasks - checklist for subtask and when you want to put more details into it, you need it be a card.

Comment: If you can't tell beforehand about a big task / sub checklist item then you have no choice but to do it the way you are.

Comment: Yeah. The "big task" becomes big when the time comes i.e. unforeseen.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the entire list of subtasks and copy them into a card like so: https://trello.com/c/M56M90xj/16-create-new-cards-from-a-spreadsheet-or-list

The card must then still be linkedin if you so wish it.

Possibly there could be a way to create an api script for it with a browser extension

Comment: Thanks but not clear enough for me though...

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a way to [do it with Butler here](https://trello.com/c/TYStNB3K/219-when-a-checklist-item-is-converted-to-a-card-add-link-sourcecardlink-and-add-the-sky-child-label-to-the-card-and-move-the-card-t).

But it looks like the [Butler transition from an external tool to being a power-up is not complete](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/Butler-power-up-can-t-do-what-Command-Builder-could/qaq-p/1052289), or they just cut scope on its abilities, so one cannot do what I want to do (at least yet).

Improving on [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/135851/238269), the best idea I have to shorten your steps is to:

1. Click convert to card
2. Scroll down to card activity, you'll see a new entry there with something like: "xxxx converted `checklist_item_desc` from a checklist item on this card". Right-Click the `checklist_item_desc` and copy the link.
3. Back on your checklist, add new item, paste the url. Trello will replace the url with the title of the new card. If you click on it, it'll also take you to the new card.

Comment: Great thanks! This helps doing it faster