# How to convert Trello checklist item to card without deleting it from checklist?

Tags: trello

When I click `Convert To Card` on Trello checklist item it converts it to a card but removes the item from the list.

Is it possible to `Convert To Card` but not to delete the original item from the list?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible without a little bit of work. I usually do this:

1. Click convert to card
2. Scroll down to card activity, you'll see a new entry there with something like: "xxxx converted `<checklist_item_desc>` from a checklist item on this card". Click the `<checklist_item_desc>` to go to your new card.
3. Copy the new card url (from the address bar)
4. Back to your master card, on checklist, add new item, paste the url. Trello will replace the url with the title of the new card. If you click on it, it'll also take you to the new card.

Comment: > _Scroll down to card activity_ helped me saving my time!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way may be to:

1. COPY the card using the Copy button to the right inside the card.
   Select only the items you want to copy (Checklists for example) and give the new card a different title.
2. Close the original card and open the new copy
3. Use the copied card to convert the checklist item(s) to card(s)
4. Delete the copied card. Select "Share and more..." from the bottom right of the card.  Then select Delete from the card # line at the bottom.
5. Confirm Delete.

You now have a new card based on the items you selected from the original card without losing any of the original items in the original card.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround, that when you check and then uncheck a checklist item an new card is created without deleting the checklist item.

This is obviously a workarround, which has the disadvantage that a card is created everytime you uncheck an itum

Create an automation:

```
when an item is unchecked in a card in list "projects", 
create a new card with title "{checklistitemname}" in list "next"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be:

1. Convert the item to a card
2. Copy the card link
3. Add the link as a checklist item  back to the card

Answer (score -1):

I really want to do this, convert a checklist item to a card without deleting it, because I like to create task cards from lists, but I also could't find a way to do this.

I think the easiest way may be to:

1 - copy checklist item text

2 - create a new card

3 - paste text as card title